# How to implement Firebase Query to find the maximum value of a firebase database child?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a question/answer app (like Quora), using Firebase Realtime Database as backend. The question details are uploaded under the child of an unique question id like this,

[image: Questions],

Answer details are uploaded under the child of an unique answer id, under the referring question id, like this,

[image: Answers]

I want to display each unique question along with the only answer that got the maximum no. of upvotes among all the answers for that particular question, on the home page (somewhat like Quora). But I cannot find a possible solution to this. Probably Firebase Query should be used but I cannot understand how to implement it. This is how I am currently displaying the answers.

```
private void getAnswers() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Answers");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            answerList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot1.getChildren()) {
                    answer = dataSnapshot.getValue(Answer.class);
                    answerList.add(answer);
                }
            }
            Collections.reverse(answerList);
            answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

But this displays all the answers for a particular question resulting in showing the same question along with its various answers in the recycler view item layout (which is not I want).
Here, is the adapter class.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AnswerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Answer answer = answerList.get(position);

        holder.tvAnswer.setText(answer.getAnswer());
        showDetails(holder.ivProfile, holder.tvQuestion, holder.tvName, holder.tvBio, answer.getQid(), answer.getPublisher());

        holder.ivUpvote.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.ivUpvote.getTag().equals("upvote")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Votes")
                        .child(answer.getId()).child("upvotes").child(currentUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Votes")
                        .child(answer.getId()).child("downvotes").child(currentUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Votes")
                        .child(answer.getId()).child("upvotes").child(currentUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
            updateUpvotes(answer.getQid(), answer.getId());
        });

        onUpvoting(answer.getId(), holder.ivUpvote);
        countUpvotes(answer.getId(),holder.tvUpCounter);

        holder.ivDownvote.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.ivDownvote.getTag().equals("downvote")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Votes")
                        .child(answer.getId()).child("downvotes").child(currentUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Votes")
                        .child(answer.getId()).child("upvotes").child(currentUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Votes")
                        .child(answer.getId()).child("downvotes").child(currentUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
            updateUpvotes(answer.getQid(), answer.getId());
        });

        onDownvoting(answer.getId(), holder.ivDownvote);
    }
```

This is the Upvotes database

[image: Upvotes]

This is how I am counting the upvotes, the value of which is then updated using Hashmap under the "upvotes" child of Answers database.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Votes")
                .child(id).child("upvotes");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                strUpvotes = snapshot.getChildrenCount() + "";
                tvUpCount.setText(strUpvotes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Any solution/suggestions (even if I need to change the database structure) on how to display only the maximum upvoted answer for a particular question, will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is really too broad to be answered succinctly, but I'll try to give some pointers.

#### Store vote count as a number, and use `increment()`

First up: you're storing the vote count as a string, which is a bad idea. If something is a number, you should store it as a number in the database. Doing this will:

- Ensure that sorting works reliably, as strings are lexicographically sorted, which is not the same as numerical sorting once the number becomes >= 10.
- Allow you to use the `increment` operator to increment the count, as shown in the documentation on [atomic server-side increments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments).

You didn't share the code for `updateUpvotes`, but with these changes it should look something like this:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Questions");
databaseReference.child(questionId).child("upvotes").setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
```

#### Show only the answers for the current question

Your `getAnswers` function seems to read all answers for all questions as far as I can see. The first step is to reduce this to only the answers for the current question. This requires that you know the ID of the current question and pass that into `getAnswers`, which can then use it to read only that question's answers from the database:

```
private void getAnswers(questionId) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Answers");
    DatabaseReference answersReference = databaseReference.child(questionId);
    answersReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot answersSnapshot) {
            answerList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot answerSnapshot: answersSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                answer = answerSnapshot.getValue(Answer.class);
                answerList.add(answer);
            }
            Collections.reverse(answerList);
            answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
        }
    });
}
```

Next up...

#### Only showing the most upvoted answer for the current question

To only show the most upvoted answer, we'll need to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). Queries in Firebase work on the basis of first ordering all child nodes on a given value, and then filtering and/or limiting the child nodes on that value.

In this case we want to order them on the (now numeric, see above) `upvotes` value, and then return the last node from the list only. So:

```
DatabaseReference answersReference = databaseReference.child(questionId);
Query topAnswerQuery = answersReference.orderByChild("upvotes").limitToLast(1);
topAnswerQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot answersSnapshot) {
        ...
```

The rest of your code remains the same, but now you only get one result in the loop.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your suggestion, I have saved the upvotes in long format using increment. I understood rest of this answer, but problem is I cannot find a way to retrieve the `questionID` from Answers database. I tried creating another db ref containing only the `questionID` for the answered ones and putting all of them in a list, but on using `for(String questionID : questionList)` and inside it `ref.child(questionID)` only the id of latest question is retrieving along with its max upvoted answer. Any suggestions on how to retrieve the questionID.

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine how that is yet another problem in your use-case. As said though, this is really way too broad a topic to cover in a single question. I recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and following the guidance in there to isolate this new problem, and then seeing if you can find an existing answer for that, or posting a new question with a *much* smaller scope for it.